# Style Inheritance of React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles

Let's say we have `<View>` like so:

```
<View>
    <Text h4 style={{color: theme.colors.success}}>Heading</Text>
    <Text>Normal text</Text>
    <Text style={{color: theme.colors.warning}}>Warning text</Text>
</View>
```

I need every child of the `<View>` to be centered in that View.

I tried adding `style={{textAlign: 'center'}}` to parent `<View>` but it does not working.

How to do it and not manually add `style={{textAlign: 'center'}}` to each child component?

Comment: Have you tried `alignItems` and `justifyContent` in the `View`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To center elements vertically.

```
<View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center'}}>
  ...
</View>
```

To center elements horizontally.

```
<View style={{flex:1,alignItems:'center'}}>
  ...
</View>
```

To center in both horizontal and vertical direction.

```
<View style={{flex:1,alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
  ...
</View>
```

I have added `flex:1` so as to stretch screen.you can also set fixed `width,height`

Note that in React Native all elements are layed in column wise manner by default.It is opposite of web.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this

```
<View style = {{flex : 1, justifyContent : 'center',alignContent : 'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
    <Text h4 style={{color: theme.colors.success}}>Heading</Text>
    <Text>Normal text</Text>
    <Text style={{color: theme.colors.warning}}>Warning text</Text>
</View>
```